# Splice on ObservableArray leads to crash

Tags: nativescript

I have a problem with ObservableArrays' splice-method.

I want to remove a specific item from my observable array, 
and to do this I use splice.

My code snippet:

```
let index = this.myItems.indexOf(item);
console.log(index)
this.myItems.splice(index, 1);
```

This just makes my app crash, it doesn't throw any error messages at all. I cannot understand why. The printout works just fine, the index is defined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I try slice with a hardcoded index, like this.myItems.splice(0,1) it also crashes.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the crash with [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=WHzFTg). Would you mind sharing a complete example where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Can you try with a free `ObservableArray`? My guess is that something depends on `this.myItems` and crashes when you modify it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I solved this problem without using splice this time. Will update if it gets relevant again.